# Graphics problem after updating to Kernel 3.11 with Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: unity, kernel

I am new to ubuntu.I have a 64 bit intel processor with ATI 6570 graphics card. Now Ubuntu 13.04 is working fine with stock kernel(3.8). But as I read somewhere that kernel 3.11 do support ATI graphics card better, I tired updating them with no success. I tried 3.11.6 3.11.4 3.11.0 but with all of them I am facing the same problem ... after installing them and restart, the screen resolution get distorted and the unity becomes too slow transparency in dash and the launcher is also lost.

Now whatever little I know , this may be related with graphics diver either they are not present or the graphic card is not turned on. Can some one help with this. And yeah i tried ubuntu 13.10 that worked fine but it has some bugs.

and yeah please pardon me for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same problem as you are facing.

I compiled the kernel and found out that a newly compiled kernel does not contains driver that provides 3D-Acceleration function. There is just an open-source driver.

So I downloaded a official driver from http://amd.com (ATI = AMD now). It is an *.run file. Run it in terminal and install the driver.

The official driver is named `fglrx`, you can type a `lsmod` to figure it out.

So to solve it just to:

1. Download driver from http://amd.com
2. Install it
3. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Thank YOu @Madmike for giving your valuable time.

But I wasn't looking for the proprietary drivers.I searched a bit and then found out that the linux firmware is missing few files regarding graphcs card (radeon).

here is the link for some of the missing files (http://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/). I downloaded the truks ( I have 6570 and turks are the drivers name.. or whtever they are dont know actually) and replaced them with files in lib/firmware/radeon. And Everything worked out to be fine.